# Need to strip out some text but can't determine selector

Tags: jquery

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/THcqY/) that shows an example of the original text and the desired result.

I am trying to find text that occurs at the begging of a div and strip it out.

This code finds the occurrences but I can't determine how to remove the strings.

```
$(function () {
    var foundin = $('.snippet:contains("...")');
    foundin.css('color', 'red');
});
```

I do not have control over the format of the original text in the example.

Examples that are added to the fiddle are most appreciated.

This is the best way for me to understand and continue my learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the `b` element and remove it's previous sibling:

```
$('.snippet').find('b:contains("...")').each(function(){
   if (this.previousSibling) this.previousSibling.remove();
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmXgG/

By using `.add()` method:

```
$('.snippet').find('b:contains("...")').each(function(){
   $(this).add(this.previousSibling).remove();
});
```

which is the same as:

```
$([this, this.previousSibling]).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/THcqY/31/

```
$(function () {
    var foundin = $('.snippet:contains("...")');
    foundin.remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/THcqY/36/

```
$(function () {
    $('.snippet').find( ':contains("...")').remove();

});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to remove the entire line—just the segment that contains the date and the ellipsis.  The Desired Result shows what I'm trying to get.